# Finding prime numbers within a range python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops, position

I am supposed to write a program to change a string if that position number is not a prime number but I can't seem to figure out how to make the first position, for example position 2, prime, and make the rest of the positions that can be divisible by 2, turn into N. Below is what I currently have and I am an int error. If anyone can help me out, I would really appreciate it. Thank you

```
while True:
    number = int(input("Enter a number greater than 10: "))
    if number < 10:
        print("Invalid input. Try again")
    else:
        break

n_list = ["P"] * (number + 1)
n_list[0] = "N"
n_list[1] = "N"

for i in range(n_list):
    if int(n_list[i]) % 2 == 0:
        n_list[i] = "N"

print(n_list)
```

Comment: I think you would catch less downvotes if you did not paste your homework verbatim. After that, OP actually does provide own code and some description of where its stuck.

Comment: (However, "I am getting an error" is not an acceptable error description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you probably get an error because range takes an integer, not a generator, try instead `for i in n_list` or `for i in range(len(n_list))`. As for the approach of the problem, you dont need to loop from 2 to n, there is a smarter way. But we are not here to solve that problem for you, only to guide you to find eventual errors that you may present us. With that said, best of luck to you!

PS:
A little more guidance
[Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.google.se/search?q=eratosthenes%20sieve&oq=eratosthenes%20sieve&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.12522j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=sieve%20of%20eratosthenes)

EDIT:
The error i'm referring to is

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give you the answer to your homework, but I do want to help so I will guide you a little.

I see 2 issues with what you've provided. First, you are using the incorrect variable for your range. You want a number, not a list.

Second, you cannot compare if "P" is evenly divisible 2. You can only check if a number is.

Hope this helps and good luck.

EDIT: To clarify, there are more issues, but these 2 will give errors.